# difference between $this->data and $this->request->data?

Tags: cakephp-2.1

In cakephp 2.1 whats the difference between `$this->data` and `$this->request->data`?

Answer (score 10):

`$this->data` was used till cakephp 1.3

`$this->request->data` has replaced the `$this->data` array from cakephp 2.x onwards.

For backward compatibility `$this->data` is also still supported.

`$this->request` represents `CakeRequest` object and is accessible in `Controller`, `Views` and `Helpers`.

For more info : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html